# Download large zip file from azure blob and unzip

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, c#-ziparchive

I have currently below code which downloads a zip file from blob using SAS URI, unzips it and uploads the content to a new container

```
        var response = await new BlobClient(new Uri(sasUri)).DownloadAsync();
        using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(response.Value.Content))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName).GetBlobClient(entry.FullName);
                using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

The code for me fails with "stream too long" exception: **System.IO.IOException: Stream was too long. at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)**.

My zip file size is 9G. What would be a better way to get around this exception? I'd like to avoid writing any files to disk.

Comment: is this framework or core ?

Comment: It is dot net core

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure API, does `DownloadAsync` download the entire content to memory, or it returns a stream and content get processed as they are downloaded? Maybe ZipArchive can work on a stream without downloading the whole content into memory?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Tarostar Posted the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution worked for me. Instead of using DownloadAsync, use OpenReadAsync

```
var response = await new BlobClient(new Uri(sasUri)).OpenReadAsync(new BlobOpenReadOptions(false), cancellationToken);
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(response))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName).GetBlobClient($"{buildVersion}/{entry.FullName}");
        using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
        {
           await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is

1. .Net has a finite size for an array (depending on the platform).
2. *Arrays* back *streams* as a buffer or in memory data store.
3. On 64-bit platforms the array size is 2 gigabytes
4. You want to put a 9 gig stream (backed by an array) on the Large Object Heap.

So, you will need to allow larger objects (somehow)

[Allow large objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#allow-large-objects)

- In .Net Framework 4.5+ you can set the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` project Element
- In core you will need to set the *Environment Variable* `COMPlus_gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`

However, putting 9 gigs of anything on the *large object heap* is problematic, it's inefficient for the GC among other issues, and you should really avoid the LOH as much as you can.

Note depending on the library, and what you have access to. There might be less *LOHy* ways to do this. If you can supply your own streams / data structures there are libraries which can break up buffers so they don't get allocated aggressively on the LOH via things like `ReadOnlySequence` and Microsofts little known `RecyclableMemoryStream`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out the environment variable. I am using standard azure blob and dot net compression libraries. Do you have any suggestion on what other libraries would be better instead?

Comment: @user1097128 no, surprisingly I have never really had a need for this type of zip shenanigans. If you find a solution be sure to post it